# Closest selector affects more than one element

Tags: jquery

I have an asp.net application that uses a grid control with three check box columns side-by-side. The boxes in the first column are enabled; the next two are disabled. I tried to write a JQuery function that will enable the adjoining check box in the second column when a user checks a box in the first column. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("[id$='FirstCheckBox']").click(function() {
                var td = $("td", $(this).closest("tr"));
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $("input[type=checkbox]", td).prop("disabled", false);
                }
                else {
                    $("input[type=checkbox]", td).prop("disabled", true).prop("checked", false);
                    $(this).prop("disabled", false);
                }    
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This function works fine when I have only two checkbox columns. But when I add a third column with disabled checkboxes, the function enables the box in that column as well. I thought the closest selector only selects one element but it seems to be selecting two. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: given `$(selector).closest(something)`, if  `selector` contains more than 1 element, it will find the closest `something` to *each element*, so if your selector has **n** elements, `closest` will return *up to* **n** elements. https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: `$("td", $(this).closest("tr"))` this is causing the problem as it returns multiple `tds`

Comment: can you add jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML and CSS so that your problem can be reproduced, and more easily answered?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going all the way up to the parent `tr` element, simply go up to the closest `td` and look for the next cell over using the jQuery `next()` method.

You can generalize this by changing your code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tableId").on('click', 'input:checkbox:not(:disabled)', function() {
            var $nextTd = $(this).closest("td").next('td');
            if (! $nextTd.length) { return; } // already in last column
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("input[type=checkbox]", $nextTd).removeProp("disabled");
            }
            else {
                $("input[type=checkbox]", $nextTd)
                    .prop("disabled", 'disabled')
                    .removeProp("checked");
                $(this).removeProp("disabled");
            }    
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you map the check boxes into an array of element objects and use the index within the array to control which check box you want to enable/disable.
I was thinking something like this: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/trr4bnxv/)

```
var chx = $('input[type="checkbox"]');       // Store the elements
chx.change(function(){                       // Set the event listener
    var i = chx.index(this);                 // Get the index of the clicked element
    $(chx[i + 1]).prop('disabled', function(i, val){
        return !val;                         // Return the opposite state of the element indexed after the triggered element
    });
});
```

It has the benefit of being short and sweet, and allows you to control by index rather than conditionals. I suppose you could add conditionals as well if you wanted further control.

Here is an example of using a condition to limit functionality of certain elements within the array. This one limits events from happening to any elements in the array after the first.

```
var chx = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
chx.change(function(){
    var i = chx.index(this);
    if(i == 0){
        $(chx[i + 1]).prop('disabled', function(i, val){
            return !val;
        });
    }
});
```

This is an even shorter version since you only need it applied to the first checkbox, but it still allows you to skip doing DOM traversal.

```
var chx = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
$(chx[0]).change(function(){
    $(chx[1]).prop('disabled', function(i, val){
        return !val;
    });
});
```

I also updated the fiddle to reflect this change.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: That almost works except it enables the check box in the third column when a box in the second column is clicked which I don't want. I tried setting a conditional on the function like this: if ($(this).id$ = 'FirstCheckBox') {    ...   but it is not recognized. Is the conditional syntax wrong?

Comment: Sure I'll look it over and see if I can stop that.